# i need help for my samsung galaxy note 4

Tags: samsung

Does anyone tried or knows how to root a LOCKED Samsung galaxy note 4 exynos versions without changing or replacing the stock firmware safely? The reason is, I just want to install the galaxy s6 or s7 theme on my note 4 just to change the user interface for a new look. For example like changing the orange color sms interface. However, I don't want to use any third party sms app.

Model number-  SM-N910C 
Android  version-  5.1.1 lollipop
Android security patch level-  2016-07-01
Baseband version-  N910CXXU1COJ5
Kernel version-  3. 10. 9-6035384
dpi@SWDD6014 #1
Wed Jul 6 18:32:42 KST 2016
Build number-  LMY47X.N910CXXS2CPG1

References- http://androidflagship.com/12039-install-galaxy-s6-theme-engine-on-galaxy-s5-s4-and-note-4
http://www.androidsage.com/2016/05/04/download-samsung-galaxy-s7-apps-and-features-for-note-4-5-s6-more/

Comment: Have you checked [How To ROOT for NOTE 4 (ALL NOTE 4 versions) - LOLLIPOP 5.1.1 WORKING](http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4/general/root-note-4-sm-n910c-t2977948)

Comment: yes but i am not sure yet if it will work on my build number- LMY47X.N910CXXS2CPG1.

Comment: i am referring on this build number- LMY47X.N910CXXU2COJ5 on the download file which is not match on my note 4 build number- LMY47X.N910CXXS2CPG1

Comment: should work fine